# How to require Stateless Functional Components (Unknown module _createWrapper?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, stateless

I'm trying to learn how to use Stateless Functional Components, and require it like this:

```
const Button = require('./components/Button');
```

And in Button.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const { Text,   View,   TouchableOpacity,} = ReactNative;
const Button = () => {
    return  (
    <View><Text>Button</Text></View>
    );
}
export default Button;
```

This gives me:

> Requiring unknown module "./_createWrapper".If you are sure the module
>   is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".

If I do it inline, like this, it works:

```
const Button = () => 
    <View><Text>Button</Text></View>
```

But since I'd like to keep it as a reusable component, I want it in a file. How should I do?

Comment: This is so strange. I created a new file, called MyButton.js, and used a very similar script. And it worked. Now I copied this exact same script to Button.js, and get the "createWrapper" error again. So it seems to be something erraneous with the file.

Comment: Never mind, I'm sorry. It was a confusion of file paths. I had two open files, and the button.js that was actually included had a totally different code, which somehow was incompatible since the upgrade of react native. Hope this helps someone, and the require/import answer is still valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require is a commonJs import syntax and export default is ES6 export syntax.

so stick to one thing commonjs or ES6 Modules.

In Button.js while exporting

use `module.exports = Button;`

or you can use es6 import statements while importing

`import Button from './components/Button'`

Comment: Very strange, I tried that but I still get the same error. Hmm.. i don't know if the stack trace would help, i'll try to paste that into my original question